# How to copy a .img file into the Z:drive of Dosbox?

Tags: copy, dosbox

While trying to run an `.img` file in DosBox on Ubuntu 22.04, I was wondering: How do I copy a `example.img` file from Ubuntu filepath: `/home/username/some_img.img` to: `Z:/some_dir` on dosbox? (Such that I can run it with: `imgmount a "Z:\some_dir\some_img.img" -t iso`)

Answer (score 0):

According to [these instructions](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/IMGMOUNT) one does not even have to copy the files/folder, one can give dosbox access to that folder, with:

```
mount c "/home/username"
```

Next one can unpack that iso with:

```
C:
imgmount a "D:\some_img.img" -t iso
```

And then one open that unpacked iso with:

```
D:
run_some_setup.exe
```